# Howto: Limit access to my facebook application

Tags: facebook, accessibility

I developed an application for my masters class, that I want to limit ONLY to my masters class.

Can I somehow limit the access? Or even connect the limit to the users in a group?

*edit* In addition: if I have all the fbids of the users I want to have access to my app in my database, can I limit the view in the profile box? it seems facebook limits what one can do there a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You can add all the people in your masters class as "developers" of the app and put it in sandbox mode. Then only developers can access it. Although you have to be "friends" with the person in order to add them as a developer. Facebook will then restrict access.

You can also put a user ID filter in your application. Get all the user IDs of the people in your masters class, then match the current user against the list. If the ID is not in the list, you can drop them on a page to request access so you can log the ID and user info (i.e. name). You can then review the info and expand the list if needed.

Comment: Brent: the second option sounds awesome!

to get that right:

myserver: IDs of facebook users in my msql db
facebook canvas: display "your not on the list" if user is not in the db.

but how can I prevent them from putting the app in their profile box? can I do the same "your not on the list" in the profile box as well?

Comment: The profile box won't appear unless you post content to it first. Facebook won't even show the "add to profile" button. You can't prevent someone adding it as a tab. But the user ID of the tab "owner" is passed when a tab is loaded, so you can adjust the content accordingly. Or just don't enter a tab URL, then no one can add it as a tab.

Comment: to sum things up:
I can change the stuff the program displays in the profile box according to the user id but I can NOT prevent user from installing it unless I use the sandbox mode.

Can you give me a yes or no on that, your my hero! ;)